# How can I clear the cache of an swt.Image on macos?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt

I'm developing an application using Eclipse and SWT.
If I do the following on a mac, the second file has the same contents as the first one.
[There was a bug in SWT](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339132) that was solved nearly a decade ago that was related with how swt.GC was disposed.  But in my case it's not being disposed.

It seems there's a cache being held somewhere, but I couldn't find a way to get rid of it.

My code, simplified:

```
Image myImg = new Image( Display.getDefault(), 100, 100 );
GC mygc = new GC( myImg );

// draw something

// Saves the image to a file.
saveImage( myImg );

// draw something else on the same image.

// Saves the image to another file.
saveImage( myImg );

myImg.dispose();
mygc.dispose();
```

If I do this after saving the first file, and before the extra drawing operations, the problem is solved:

```
mygc.dispose();
mygc = new GC( myImg );
```

But I don't want to dispose and create a new GC, because of performance issues.
On Windows it works perfectly.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no cache. You need to show us a proper [mre] - something we can test.

Comment: Thanks, Greg, I'll do that.  I though the code I supplied would be enough.

Comment: There's something wrong indeed:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543796